# How to wait till require finished in dojo

Tags: dojo, require, synchronized

I'm providing an infrastructure for other developers, and i'm using Dojo for it.

In my Init function i'm using the 'require' method (of course) which one of the parameters are the callback function when all the modules have been loaded.

The problem is that the client don't want to use callbacks. He wants to call me and line after to use me (to make my Init method synchronized) - and give him the code back after we for sure finished loading our modules.

My Code

```
<script src=..../dojo.js></script>

function Init()
{
   var loaded = false;

   require(["...myFiles..."], 
      function()
      {
          loaded = true;
      });

   // Whatever to do here or some other way to hold till the require operation finished
   while (!loaded) // :)
}
```

My Client side

```
  Init();
  myFiles.DoSomething();
```

Is it possible to do it ?
To make require synchronized or do something else that waits till it's over ?
To return from the init method only when the require method finished ?

Answer (score 2):

You can either call your next function from within the require response, or use a deferred object.

```
 function Init()
 {
    var d =  new dojo.Deferred();

    require(["...myFiles..."], 
       function()
       {
           d.resolve(true);
       });
   return d;
 }
```

Other file

```
 Init().then(myFiles.DoSomething);
```

Comment: I will correct my question. I want to somehow block the Init method until the require ended. That it will stop the client code till i'm sure that my modules loaded. The client does not want to put all his code in a callback or 'then' (of Defferred object).

Comment: Since the require is an async call you have to use one of those methods, or use the flag like you have with a javascript timer event.

Comment: Problem is that require function is a callback.  Only option you have is to use the old school dojo.require for each package and turn djconfig async to false

Comment: Right, but what's the point of using dojo in async mode if you are constrained by your customer's requirement that it should NOT be async ?

Comment: ok guys, I got the point - It's exactly what i thought. The thing that the client kind of convinced me when he said that he doesn't want to be depended on my Init, and then continue his code after my callback. His plan was to try - catch my init, and continue by his code. But well, you can't get it all (He can't get it all). Thanks guys for helping

Comment: My solution was telling my client that what he wants it's not possible. And after arguing the decision as turned - Thanks to you guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Make your initializer be a module, say "my/Files", and make your init and doSomething functions be static methods of that module :

in "my/Files.js"

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", 
    ...<your other required dependencies>
], function(declare){

    var myFiles = declare(null, {});

    myFiles.init = function(){
        // Your initialization code
    }

    myFiles.doSomething = function(){ ... }

    return myFiles;
});
```

In your html :

```
<script type="dojo/require">
    myFiles : "my/Files"
</script>
```

Then you can use it in your javascript like :

```
myFiles.init();
myFiles.doSomething();
```

Comment: This thing is that i don't have HTML part in my side of the infrastructure. I'm only java script. And for inserting this script tag via js I would need again to use the callback onLoad of the element

Comment: So, how do you insert the dojo.js library in the html ?

Comment: Creating script element and document.head.appendChild... The thing is that even for this we need the onLoad event of the element to make sure the script is loaded. But there the client was OK with the callback.. I'm not justifying my client wish, I just thought maybe there is an easy solution for it that i'm missing