# Dojo return value from within require

Tags: javascript, dojo, require

How do I return a value from within a dojo require block? Say I have a set up like this:

```
<div class = "people">
    <span class = "name"> Joe Bloggs </span> the Baker <br />
    <span class = "name"> John Smith </span> the Chef <br />
</div>


function getNames () {
    require(["dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {

        var names = [];
        query (".name").forEach (function (node) {
            names.push (node.innerHTML);
        });

        return names;
    });
}

function doSomethingWithNames () {

    var names = getNames (); // names is always undefined

}
```

I know why it's happening - the require block is executing asynchronously, and so the variable names in doSomethingWithNames is assigned before getNames has returned. But how do I get around it?

Comment: Either use the call back like crowebird stated, or you can use the dojo.deferred functionality. like in::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406681/how-to-wait-till-require-finished-in-dojo/17407020#17407020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a custom callback:

```
function getNames (callback) {
    require(["dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {

        var names = [];
        query (".name").forEach (function (node) {
            names.push (node.innerHTML);
        });

        callback(names);
    });
}

function doSomethingWithNames () {

    getNames (function(names) {
        //do your stuff with the return here
        //names will now be populated
    });

}
```